# SharePoint Migration from 2010 to Office 365 Permission Issue

Tags: permissions, office-365, migration, groups

I am migrating permission from SharePoint 2010 to Office 365 while migrating it.
I have seen those group are not moved which has Limited access.
I am using metalogix tool to migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, SharePoint Online does not show Limited Access permission level even though it is assigned to a particular user or group. However, you can still verify the existence of the Limited Access permission level using REST API. For example, https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid(10)/roledefinitionbindings

Unlike other permission levels, the Limited Access permission level is automatically created when you break permission inheritance of an item. Microsoft uses it for the core functionality of SharePoint platform, it cannot be altered by any API or third party vendor. You can simply ignore the aspect of not migrating Limited Access permission level as in source SharePoint 2010 environment.